# how to draw concentric circles in an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

Here is my code....
I want to draw concentric circles in a fingerprint image.. please help

```
clear all
clc

id=imread('C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\DB1\101_2.tif');
a=size(id);
sd=a/2;
s=3;

circle([sd(1),sd(2)],3,1000,':');
circle([sd(1),sd(2)],6,1000,':');
circle([sd(1),sd(2)],9,1000,':');
circle([sd(1),sd(2)],12,1000,':');
circle([sd(1),sd(2)],15,1000,':');
circle([sd(1),sd(2)],18,1000,':');
```

Answer (score 2):

use hold on then plot the fingerprint